# Creating custom for loops when specifying multiple indexes [PYTHON]

Tags: python, loops, indexing

Essentially, this is what my text file looks like:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,3,2,5,4
2,4,5,3,1

etc
```

What I want to do, is make a for loop which goes through each index but not the one I have chosen to be ignored.
In this instance, I have made a variable [index] to indicate which index should be ignored. This variable is generated by the program and is unnecessary other than its value as an index. 
Lets say; `variable = 1`

So in this instance, I'd want the 2nd number of each line to be ignored for every line. 
How would I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to loop through your data while getting access to both values and indices:

```
for d in data:
    for i,el in enumerate(d):
        if i is not variable:
```

Here `data` is a list with sublists, each sublist representing a line of your file. The loop uses `enumerate` to loop through each sublist - `i` is the index of the current element and `el` is the element. With this you can use if to check if `i` is not equal to `variable`, the index that you don't want to process - and if it is not, move on to the processing.

Alternatively you can read the file without including that particular index:

```
variable = 1;

data = [];
with open('test_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp = line.strip().split(',')
        del temp[variable]
        data.append(temp)
```

Here the program simple uses `del` to remove the element at the index `variable` and appends the remaining elements to the final dataset.

To load the whole file as it is just remove the `del temp[variable]` line in the loading part of the program. The you can use the loop with `enumerate` to exclude the index you don't want to process.

Comment: How would I make the file's string content into a sublist, and also, I don't want to make any changes to the original file nor make a duplicate.

Comment: The file is already a list of sublists, each being a line of file like this `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`. Do you mean you need to change the strings into numbers or so? Second question - you want to load the whole file and not change what you loaded (`data` here) or you don't want to load the whole file, rather, you want to process it line by line and discard each line after processing?

Comment: Yes, I want to load the whole file and not change what was loaded in file beforehand.

Comment: Then just remove the `del ...` line - that will load your file, and then you can use the loop in the beginning of the answer. I'll add that comment to the answer.

Comment: One more thing - in the processing loop you can also use a temporary list for each line where you apply `del` to remove the index you don't want to process and then process that whole line/temporary list.